# Wix type page transitions? how to remake from scratch

Tags: css, animation

Not sure if it's an appropriate question, but I will still ask..

Any advice on how WIX (the simple website builder) sites do the page transitions? such as transiting into a page with a Left to Right swipe in and loading the page on demand?

I have tried searching for tutorials but I am not too sure what to look for exactly.
Are these CSS and a combination of jquery?

Any advice would be appreciated.

An example site of the said transition: 
http://www.alllinkmedical.com/

Thank You.

*EDIT* I mean to ask: where do I start looking at to create such page transitions on sites built from scratch

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wix.com/support/main/html5/wix-editor/pages#Changing+Your+Page+Transitions
Taken from Wix website:

Changing Your Page Transitions
You can choose a page transition for your pages. The page transition determines how your pages will shift and what your visitors will see when they navigate from page to page.

To change your page transitions:

1. From the left side of the Editor, click the page icon to open Pages.
2. Under Page Transitions, click the drop-down menu and select a transition.

Now if you want a custom transition, I'd recommending looking at jQuery

Comment: EDIT So sorry, I mean to ask: where do I start looking at to create such page transitions on sites built from scratch